# Cant delete folders

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to delete folders in Ubuntu 14.04 but the delete option isn't available.The folders can be deleted using the terminal or the delete button but there is no delete option wen right clicked What should i do in this situation?

Comment: You have not permission to this. use `gksudo nautilus` and then Delete folder that you want.

Comment: It says "Move to Trash" not "delete".

Comment: do shift+delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under **Nautilus(The file manager)=>Edit Menu=>Preferences=>Behavior Tab**
Check the **"Include a Delete command that bypasses Trash"** checkbox

That will add a "Delete" entry whenever you right clicked a file

Comment: Thanks so far for the answers but how do i get Nautilus

Comment: ok thanks much your answer helped i got it to work

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal

```
sudo nautilus
```

and then enter your password, it will be temporary, but you will have full read-write permission for every folder and file your computer.